# can't play file from .net server with AMR narrowband H.264 encoding

Tags: android, iphone, amr

1. AMR narrowband is the default audio encoding for videos captured in Android 2.1
2. When I upload this to my server and try and view it either in the chrome webbrowser on my mac or streaming from my iPhone it does't play (it does play in quicktime if I copy it locally to my mac)

Is there a way to get this to play?  Am I missing a mime-type?  It plays fine locally on the android phone in in the android browser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Server was fine.  Turns out the issue is that iOS doesn't support AMR encoding (at least within videos).

Comment: Hello Scott. How did you solve this problem? Thanks for answer.